# What does my installed .cer certificate not show in IIS?

Tags: security, iis, ssl

I was provided a `.cer` file for a certificate to install on my local machine. I have opened it, gone through the wizard to install it, and can not find it listed under `Server Certificates` in IIS. I even tried re-installing the `.cer` file and dictate the location of the cert store by placing it in `Trusted Root Certification Authorities` just to see if it would work, and it made no difference.

I know when I import `.pfx` files using IIS I've always had success with them being usable in IIS. How come my installed `.cer` certificate does not show in IIS even though the installation and import was a success?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to complete a certificate request in order to "install" it.

Go into server certification. Choose complete certificate request, select the certificate(.cer), and pretty much that's it.

Check http://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-microsoft-iis-7.htm for exact procedure.

Comment: That was it! I didn't know I needed to complete the request and that's why it was not showing up in IIS.

Comment: After completing the request also make sure that the local [IIS_IUSRS has **Read** permission on the certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44643853/1986541).