# Certificate not found when deploying IdentityServer 4 to Azure VM

Tags: azure, .net-core, identityserver4

I'm getting this cert issue while deploying IdentityServer 4 (ASP.NET Core 1.1) to Azure VM (Windows Server 2012 R2).

```
crit: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Unhandled exception: Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: The system cannot find the file specified
         at System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey.Open(String keyName, CngProvider provider, CngKeyOpenOptions openOptions)
         at System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey.Open(String keyName, CngProvider provider)
         at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.GetPrivateKey[T](Func`2 createCsp, Func`2 createCng)
         at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.GetRSAPrivateKey()
```

This will work on local dev computer and I cannot figure it out why. I install the cert on My (Local Machine) store on the VM.

Can anyone help on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the solution here:

http://www.daves-blog.net/post/2014/06/16/X509Certificate-The-System-cannot-find-the-file-specified.aspx

Apparently, I need to enable the Load User Profile on the Application Pool. However, the error now changes to this:

```
crit: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
  Unhandled exception: Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: Keyset does not exist
     at System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey.Open(String keyName, CngProvider provider, CngKeyOpenOptions openOptions)
     at System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey.Open(String keyName, CngProvider provider)
     at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.GetPrivateKey[T](Func`2 createCsp, Func`2 createCng)
     at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.GetRSAPrivateKey()
```

Looking at the issue now.

Okay, so the issue is permission to read the cert. All we have to do just go to the certificate and grant **Read** (*only*) for IIS_IUSRS.

Now it works.

Comment: What happens if the certificate in question is just an inmemory certificate and not installed anywhere on the machine?  I believe that's the recommended approach if you are going to be running IS4 inside a container and deploying certs with the application would be a security risk

Comment: Well, my client infra environment as the requirement needed to be like this, so they can rotate the cert. I personally recommend to use AzureKeyVault instead to store the PFX with HSM key for easy rotation, so there will be no certificate on the app side, even if they move to containers someday.

Comment: So to get this working you simply had the certificate in the same location as the running code to which `IIS_IUSRS` had read access to?

Comment: So you gave the user read access to the cert store? How did you manage that?

Comment: Okay, it doesn't quite add up...a certificate will be stored in their certificate store, how does the IIS user get read rights to it? Anyways, thanks.

Comment: @Ruskin just go to cert store. Right click on the cert and choose All Tasks -> Manage Private Keys. I hope that helps.

Comment: link to the blog post is dead

Answer (score 5):

If anyone is wondering how to give IIS users access to certs

1. Create / Purchase certificate. Make sure it has a private key.
2. Import the certificate into the "Local Computer" account. Best to use Certificates MMC. **Make sure to check "Allow private key to be exported"**
3. Based upon which, IIS 7.5 Application Pool's identity use one of the following.

   - IIS 7.5 Website is running under ApplicationPoolIdentity. Open MMC => Add Certificates (Local computer) snap-in => Certificates (Local Computer) => Personal => Certificates => Right click the certificate of interest => All tasks => Manage private key => Add `IIS AppPool\AppPoolName` and grant it `Full control`. Replace "*AppPoolName*" with the name of your application pool (sometimes `IIS_IUSRS`)
   - IIS 7.5 Website is running under NETWORK SERVICE. Using Certificates MMC, added "NETWORK SERVICE" to Full Trust on certificate in "Local Computer\Personal".
   - IIS 7.5 Website is running under "MyIISUser" local computer user account. Using Certificates MMC, added "MyIISUser" (a new local computer user account) to Full Trust on certificate in "Local Computer\Personal".

The above is extracted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609859/how-to-give-asp-net-access-to-a-private-key-in-a-certificate-in-the-certificate/2647003#2647003).

Comment: I agree with the above, with one exception: On bullet one, `Read` permission is sufficient for an Application Pool Identity to access a certificate.