# How to deploy IdentityServer4 on AWS

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have a .Net Core IdentityServer4 application which was hosted on a different server before and was working perfectly unti we decided to moved everything on AWS.

The problem now is we can't find a guided on how to deploy it on AWS, as a new comer in AWS things can get very confusing with their too many services.

Hope someone can help provide a documentation or instruction on how to deploy it on AWS.

Comment: IdentityServer4 is just a .NET Core app, you don't need a special guidance or documentation explicitly for IDS. Just look for one for any core 2.0 app

Comment: just made it work, I thought there is a special config to do in AWS deployment as it was working perfectly in Azure. there was an issue in Self Signed certifcate. all good now.

Comment: Was this your issue with the self-signed certificate? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44643853/2567835

I am having this issue, and these steps work for resolving it. However, we have Alpha, Beta, Demo and Production environments, all with 2+ instances, so I don't like to connect to each separate instance to configure IIS. Did you find another solution?